# 2D array that automatically adapts depending on the available size of the terminal in C

Tags: c, arrays, ioctl

We ask your help to resolve a little problem that we couldn't find the solution. We have to create an 2D-array to make a shooter game. We would create an 2D array that automatically adapts depending on the available size of the terminal, like if the size is 40*80, the array will be tab[40][80]
We have test a lot of solutions but no one is working. 
Here is the code that we used:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/dir.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stropts.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#define N 50
#define M 50

int main()
{

    // To know the size of the cols and rows 
    int col2, row2;
    char tab[col2][row2];
    const struct winsize row;
    ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, &row);
    printf("Rows: %i\n", row.ws_row);

    const struct winsize col;
    ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, &col);
    printf("Cols: %i\n", col.ws_col);

    col2=col.ws_col;
    row2=row.ws_row;


    // To show the array 
    for(i=0;i<col2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<row2;j++)
        {
            tab[i][j]='*';
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<col2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<row2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",tab[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[(sizetype)(col2)][(sizetype)(row2)]’ from type ‘void *’

Before, we would use char** tab but we don't find any informations about this. 
Thank's for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behaviour to use uninitialized variables.

```
int col2, row2;
char tab[col2][row2];
```

**You cannot assign `col2` and `row2` later and have your array `tab` get automatically resized.** Here, `col2` must be a compile-time constant or it must have a known value(variable-length array). Also, `row2` is part of the type of the element of the array. It must be a complete type. Hence, it must also be a compile-time constant or it must have a known value.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for this. With older C, you had to use dynamic memory through pointers to 1D arrays (i.e. a `char **`):

```
char **tab = NULL;

/* after you find col2 and row2 */
tab = malloc(row2 * sizeof *tab);
for (i = 0; i < row2; ++i)
    tab[i] = malloc(col2 * sizeof *tab[i]);
```

with proper error handling.

With C99, or gcc extensions to the older C, you can do it easier on the stack (knowing the sizes can't be too large):

```
/* after you find col2 and row2 */
char tab[row2][col2];
```

---

Another way of doing it dynamically is to emulate the 2D array by a 1D array:

```
/* after you find col2 and row2 */
char *tab = malloc(row2 * col2 * sizeof *tab);
```

and you access the elements as:

```
tab[i * col2 + j]
```

to access element at row `i` and column `j`. This is basically what the compiler automatically does for 2D arrays on the stack.